# How to manipulate html files under the wwwroot file in asp.net core

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, wwwroot

I working on an ASP.NET Core project. Is there any way that I can manipulate html, css, or javascript that is in my wwwwroot file?

For example I have class Uptime, that only contain property that return true or false. 
Is there any way that I can change for example css  in my html page (if is true I want for example to change color to red of my element in html(css)).

Comment: Why don't you just change css prop/class for element depending on `Uptime` property? You can do it via js or even render already prepared markup.

Comment: I put that as example, I will get data from database and c# class, how to manipulate with html under the wwwroot, is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

One way to include the CSS files in @section in the View and set a condition on the model property value.

```
@model ColorViewModel
@section styles{
@if(Model.IsRed)
{
<link href="~/css/red.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}
else
{
<link href="~/css/green.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}
}
```

Comment: I am not using razor pages, I am using html under the wwwroot folder

Answer (score 0):

I beleive that there is no special API for manipulating `wwwroot` folder in asp.net core. So you can use a common [System.IO.FileSystem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem/) package.

**Note:** I wouldn't recommend to use this approach for your needs. Static files should be static. You need to consider change css prop/class for element depending on `Uptime` property via `javascript` or return prepared markup/css/js from your `controler`.